# Caught exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided.: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk, sdk

I have installed Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) PHP SDK, created my App and updated config.php with ClientId and SecretId but when I am running any sample or any other code I get this error

> "Caught exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret)
>   provided.: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely........"

One thing I have noticed that my App Status in App center is blank.

Is there any one guide me if I am doing anything incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may encounter this problem. It was DateTime() problem in php for which you need to edit your php.ini file and edit or uncomment this line.

```
date.timezone = Europe/London
```

Make sure change zone to your zone.

Regards